# Put link to my site to google+ page related to my site via app related to that page

Tags: google-plus, google-api-python-client

I have the my own application in google api.
and google+page for this application in https://cloud.google.com/console

Is it possible to publish any links to my website by the google-api on google+page wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

While there is a [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) that supports this functionality, currently publishing sites like HoutSuite have access.